# Friendship theorem: need help with part of proof.

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose $G$ is a simple graph such that every two of its vertices have exactly one common neighbor.

The friendship theorem says that $G$ must be a friendship graph (a bunch of triangles joined at a single vertex)

[image]

The hint in the problem says to suppose for a contradiction that $G$ is not such a graph. Then supposedly $G$ must be regular (all vertices have same degree), but I don't see why.  Can someone help? Once I have this, I see how to get the contradiction to finish the proof.

EDIT: I posted [my solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1344606/963109). If you are interested, please let me know if it looks ok. If you have a simpler proof feel free to post it, I'd like to see it.

Comment: Using induction, deduce that $N[v]$ is a friendship graph; further for two vertices v and w, define $f:N(v) \to N(w)$ as: f(x)=unique common neighbor of x and w. Try to show that f is injective and hence $deg(v) \leq deg(w)$.

Comment: @Aravind Thanks for your comment.  I now have a proof, though it is a bit complicated.  I will post it here sometime today.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose every two vertices in $G$ have exactly one common neighbor, but $G$ is not a friendship graph. We show $G$ is regular.

Let $u$ and $v$ be vertices of $G$. We define an injection $f:N(u)\to N(v)$, yielding $|N(u)|\leq |N(v)|$. By symmetry the reverse inequality will follow.

Case 1: $v\notin N(u)$. Let $f(x)$ be the neighbor between $x$ and $v$. If $x\neq y$ then by uniqueness of common neighbors $f(x)=f(y)$ would imply $u=f(x)$, but then $v\in N(u)$.

Case 2: $v\in N(u)$. Since $G$ is not a friendship graph, i.e. it has no vertex that is connected to all other vertices, there is a vertex $w\notin N(u)$. For each $x\in N(u)$ let $x'$ be the vertex between $x$ and $w$. Define $f(v)=v'$ and for all other $x$ let $f(x)$ be the vertex between $x'$ and $v$.

If $x\neq v\in N(u)$ but $f(x)=f(v)$, then by uniquess of the common neighbor of $x$ and $v$ we have $u=f(v)\in N(w)$, a contradiction.

If $x\neq y\in N(u)$ with $x\neq v\neq y$ but $f(x)=f(y)$, then by uniqueness of the common neighbor of $x'$ and $y'$ we have $w=v\in N(u)$, a contradiction.